# Javascript prototype function calling from typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, prototype

I have an Angular app having multiple external JavaScript files included from `/app/asset/scripts` and working fine while calling from `<script>` tag. I am trying to call JavaScript function from angular(.ts), but it throws an error. Here is the snippet:

**src/app/asser/scripts/viewer.js**

```
function MyView(x, y) {
  //other stuffs
  this.initView(x, y); <---- error here
}

MyView.prototype.initView = function(x, y) {
  console.log("initView");
}
```

**src/app/viewer/viewer-component.ts**

```
declare var MyView: any;

export class myComponent{
  constructor(){}
  init(){
    this.view = MyView(1000, 800);
  }
}
```

While invoking the `initView` from JS. It throws the error below:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.initView is not a function
    at MyView (view.js:69)
    at RendererService.push.i2er.RendererService.SetupURL (viewer0.ts:31)
```

How this error can be resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function MyView(x, y) {
  //other stuffs
  this.initView(x, y); <---- error here
}

MyView.prototype.initView = function(x, y) {
  console.log("initView");
}
```

`MyView` is a constructor function.

In order to use `this` you should call it with `new` keyword

```js
new MyView(2,2)
```

I'm not sure that you need `declare var MyView: any;`

Comment: I tried with removing `declare var MyView: any;` and `new MyView(1000, 800)` but still issue persists

Comment: please share reproducable example in any code sandbox. Pls keep in mind, it is better to share minimum reproducable example

Comment: `declare var MyView: any;` reduces compile error in vscode and `new` keyword does the trick. thank you.